# how do I find the temperature in the stuff written below?

Tags: python, python-3.x, openweathermap

How do i find the temperature in degrees(F) from this openweathermap api:

```
{ coord: { lon: -73.36, lat: 40.81 }, weather: [ { id: 800, main: "Clear", description: "clear sky", icon: "01n" } ], base: "stations", main: { temp: 272.69, pressure: 1039, humidity: 63, temp_min: 270.15, temp_max: 275.15 }, visibility: 16093, wind: { speed: 2.6, deg: 190 }, clouds: { all: 1 }, dt: 1517014560, sys: { type: 1, id: 2100, message: 0.005, country: "US", sunrise: 1517054882, sunset: 1517090692 }, id: 0, name: "Huntington Station", cod: 200 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it's simply the temp tags.
This one is in Kelvin so you'll need to translate it

Answer (score 0):

If your json is loaded into a variable named `dic`:

```
print(dic['main']['temp'] * (9/5) - 459.67)
```

Kelvin to fahrenheit formula from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelvin).